# How to open a blob file in a new tab IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular5 project, facing one issue in IE browser. 
I am trying to download a pdf file and open in a new tab. It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE. See the below code

```
doDownload(blob: Blob,fileName:string){
 if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
 } else {
   var a = window.document.createElement('a');
   a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   a.download = fileName;
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   a.click();
   document.body.removeChild(a);
   window.open(a.href);
  }
}
```

In IE download is working but not able to open in a new tab.

Comment: In what IE version does it not work?

Comment: @daan.desmedt IE11